# Is there any way to get Mvx.MvxLinearLayout to respect android:layout_weight?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a horizontal list of items that i wish to share the available screen width equally.

Previously I had used index binding to each item and a static LinearLayout with each item having an equal layout_weight.

When I replace the static LinearLayout with an Mvx.MvxLinearLayout and ItemsSource binding, and move the markup for the items into an Itemtemplate the layout_weight is no longer respected by the MvxLinearLayout.

I've tried various ways of restructuring the item template and there seems to be no way to get this control to obey layout_weight when arranging its items.

Is there any way to get Mvx.MvxLinearLayout to respect android:layout_weight, or any alternative approach that could give me a dynamic list of items that will arrange equally given a boundary of fixed dimensions?

**Edit**

Assuming a list of 3 items, with a string property 'Name'.

This markup works as expected, giving 3 text items of equal width:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text Items[0].Name"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text Items[1].Name"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text Items[2].Name"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This Approach does not work, the layout weight is not applied correctly to the TextViews:

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_template" />
```

The ItemTemplate layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
```

Comment: Please include some code for what previously worked and what you've tried. Also what does the hierarchy viewer show as the difference?

Comment: I've added the requested info, can anyone help with this?

Comment: Was there a solution for this issue? I'm currently facing the same problem. Having a MvxLinearLayout which doesn't respect layout_weight of the items in it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, mvvmcross inserts an additional view when using MvxLinearLayout with an ItemTemplate. So instead of getting a view hierarchy:

MvxLinearLayout -> TextView

you end up with:

MvxLinearLayout -> MvxListItemView -> TextView.

The layout properties applied to the TextView, notably the weight, are therefore invisible to the LinearLayout. The MvxListItemView is primed with the default layout properties (wrap content), and no weight effects are seen.

The location where the action happens is in MvxViewGroupExtensions (e.g. Refill), where the subviews are added to the LinearLayout, and the CreateBindableView method in MvxAdapter, where the subview is packed inside an IMvxListItemView.

One way to solve this is to override the methods in MvxViewGroupExtensions, and after the views are added to update the layout properties of the MvxListItemViews (e.g. copy them from the underlying view). For example:

```
private static void Refill(this ViewGroup viewGroup, IAdapter adapter) {
    .... // rest of code
    Invalidate();
    for (int j = 0; j < viewGroup.ChildCount; j++)
    {
        var child = GetChildAt(j) as MvxListItemView;
        var param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                     0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 1.0f);
        child.LayoutParameters = param;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> any way to get `MvxLinearLayout` to respect `android:layout_weight`

None that I know of - but it sounds like you are in a perfect position to debug and experiment.

To debug layout issues, one very useful tool is the hierarchy viewer - http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html - using this on both layouts may show you what the difference is when they are actually running on a device.

The `MvxLinearLayout` is just a `LinearLayout` - it inherits from it and simply adds a data-bound `Adapter` to allow you to add/remove children dynamically - see [MvxLinearLayout.cs.](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxLinearLayout.cs.)

Based on this, one hypothesis is that maybe `LinearLayout` itself does not support `layout_weight` with such dynamic children. To investigate this:

- you could try prototyping the UI without using Mvx - does a plain LinearLayout "respect layout_weight" as you add/remove children? If the answer is yes, then what is the difference between your prototype and [MvxLinearLayout.cs.](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxLinearLayout.cs.). If the answer is no then you know that the issue is in `LinearLayout` somewhere.
- you could try looking at the LinearLayout source - e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/LinearLayout.java - this investigation may uncover some way forward - for example, it may find some way you can force the LinearLayout to remeasure and you could then call that 'force remeasure' method from the `ChildViewAdded` and `ChildViewRemoved` events.

> any alternative approach that could give me a dynamic list of items that will arrange equally given a boundary of fixed dimensions?

If the built-in layouts do not work for you, then it's pretty straight-forward to create your own custom layouts - e.g. see http://arpitonline.com/blog/2012/07/01/creating-custom-layouts-for-android/ - once you have done that, then adding binding is as simple as copying and pasting the `ViewGroup` binding code from [MvxLinearLayout.cs.](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxLinearLayout.cs.)

Comment: Is it possible to obtain click event for the linear layout item in order to act upon the clicked item (like deleting it)?